# AdMob Flutter top banner safe afrea

Tags: flutter, admob

the AdMob banner is not showing under the safe area even i have wrapped the scaffold widget with safeArea widget,check the image

i found a solution by setting anchorOffset: 24
but im wondering if there's a better solution? to push the banner under SafeArea by default for all kind of devices
thank you

```
      // TODO: Implement _loadBannerAd()
  void _loadBannerAd() {
    _bannerAd
      ..load()
      ..show( anchorType: AnchorType.top,
         anchorOffset: 24

      );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: while this is very strange..it should not be displayed out of safe area... Try to reduce size of image. and check if it's coming under safe area.